# How do you send a vector of vectors in MPI?

Tags: c++, vector, mpi, send, openmpi

So here is the problem... I have been looking at stackoverflow for a long time for a solution but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a vector of vectors of already determined length, and I just want to pass these vectors (of vectors) around in different nodes for my algorithm during synchronization. But no matter what I do, I still get segmentation errors, which I assume has something to do with my vector's memory allocation.

This is my code snippet:

```
if(world_rank == 0)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > phi_msg(K,std::vector<double>(V));
    for(int k = 0;k<K;k++)
    { 
        MPI_Sendrecv(&phi[k].front(),phi[k].size(),MPI_DOUBLE,world_rank+1,
                0, &phi_msg[k], V, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank+1,0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }

    std::cout << "Message received from " << world_rank+1 << std::endl;
}
if(world_rank == 1)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > phi_msg(K,std::vector<double>(V));
    for(int k = 0;k<K;k++)
    {
        MPI_Sendrecv(&phi[k].front(),phi[k].size(),MPI_DOUBLE,world_rank-1,
                0, &phi_msg[k], V, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank-1,0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }           
    std::cout << "Message received from " << world_rank-1 << std::endl;
}
```

Here, basically I have a V X K vector of doubles that I evaluate before, and I want to pass the newly computer vector of vectors to the other processors. I have tried doing phi_next.reserve(V) but it doesn't help either.

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code:  (128)
Failing at address: (nil)
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code:  (128)
Failing at address: (nil)
```

Comment: Have you considered [Boost MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html)?

Comment: I should have mentioned this, I won't be able to use Boost in our cluster... :(

Comment: Does `V == phi[k].size()` then?

If so, my suggestion would be to replace the &phi_msg[k] with &phi_msg[k].front() or &phi_msg[k][0]. if phi_msg is the same size as phi, then your passing a reference to a vector<double> rather than the start of the data.

Comment: Thanks sooo much! I come from a Java background, and still make idiotic mistakes such as this.

However, I would like to ask if there is a direct way to send the entire vector in one message... Or do I have to create an MPI_struct for that

Comment: You can build Boost.MPI from source in user space. Why can't you use it?

Comment: You have to use `MPI_Type_create_struct`. The reason for that is that `std::vector` itself is not an array but rather a structure that contains a pointer to the actual data storage. Therefore, `phi` ends up being a collection of pointers that could point to memory areas placed completely randomly in the address space.